# Scipy spline interpolation outside data points region

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am fitting 2d points on a 1d axis, using `scipy.interpolate.bisplrep`. This works better than the polynomial interpolation in general, but outside the points used for fitting, it gives bounded values. I can't find anything like `fill_value="extrapolate"`, that we can use with `interp1d`.

As splines are piecewise polynomials, I thought I could use the coefficients of the closest polynomial, but I don't know how.

```py
xy = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [0, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [0.1, 0]]
x, y = tuple(list(zip(*xy)))
z =  [0, 1, 1, 1.1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0.1]
spline = interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, kx=2, ky=2)

print(interpolate.bisplev([0], [0], spline)) # close to 0 as expected
print(interpolate.bisplev([1], [1], spline)) # 1.1 as expected
print(interpolate.bisplev([2], [2], spline)) # 3 as expected
print(interpolate.bisplev([3], [3], spline)) # 3 but should return way more
```

Comment: I don't think these methods support extrapolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @jared said in the comments: bisplrep/bisplev does not support extrapolation:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3361

That said, if you do not need smoothing, RegularGridInterpolator does extrapolate.

Comment: I need a bit of smoothing, and more importantly I am not on a regular grid. I accept the answer though, thank you for the information.